Can't post a question neither to Game Development nor to Game Development Meta
I created title, body and filled tags. It says "Draft saved", but when I click "Review your question" button, nothing happens. I reopened browser, put the question from scratch, tried to "Discard draft". Nothing helped.
All fields are filled, no error messages are shown.
No issues on other forums. The browser is the recent version of FireFox on Windows.
I sent the report to helpdesk yesterday, but no responses so far.
Could you please help finding the root cause and solution?
Update 1
Per requests in comments:
When I click ask the question in the development console I can see:
Uncaught TypeError: N.tex2jax is undefined
...

Additionally I can see:
Request for font "Cascadia Mono" blocked at visibility level 2 (requires 3)
ask
Google Publisher Tags is being shimmed by Firefox. 
Google Analytics and Tag Manager is being shimmed by Firefox. 

Clicking Review your question doesn't bring any new error messages.
I don't use VPN
Cookies/history clean up didn't help.

Perhaps it's related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431721/11379709

Have you tried other browsers? Are you using a VPN?

Check for errors in the developer console, see if there's a server request being rejected. Clearing cache also usually helps, since moving to CloudFlare I've seen many reports like this, most solved by clearing the local browser cache.

@RobertLongson, cookies clean up didn't help, but I found the solution (see the answer).

@ShadowWizard, thank you for the clue with the developer console. It helped to get the hint and find the solution (see the answer).

My FireFox browser under Windows 10 had Strict Enhanced Tracking Protection mode

Settings/Privacy and Security/Enhanced Tracking Protection

When I've changed it to Standard everything started to work properly.

Fixed now, see my response at I can’t post a new question on Puzzling Stack Exchange. Why not?. Thanks for the report!
